# Maven Repo: Could not resolve dependencies - Could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a pipeline for my Java/Maven projects. We have a hosted Gitlab with maven-repo enabled and have two projects where one is dependent on the other.
The dependency builds just fine and I can see the artifact deployed under the packages folder of the project. The problem is while building the parent project, it fails to find the dependency.

Below are the repository settings for both:

```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>$env{CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Below is the extra dependency added to the parent project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.abc.xyz.models</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-models</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the command I'm trying to run in parent project.

```
mvn clean validate package
```

Below is the error message:

```
[ERROR] Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc.xyz:sweta-test-parameter:jar:1.0.0.0: Failure to find com.abc.xyz.models:test-models:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in https://code.abc.com/api/v4/projects/174499/packages/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gitlab-maven has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: what are the maven goals you use?

Comment: Thank you for your reply I'm running ```mvn clean validate package``` in the parent project.

Comment: Did you ever run `mvn install` for the *test-models* project?

Comment: I guess I did run ```mvn install```